# Qual a diferença entre uma propriedade {get; set;} e uma variável pública?

Tags: c#

Estou programando em `C#` e sempre vejo usarem `propriedades` permitindo pegar e setar o valor da variável, mas qual o sentido disso? Quando deixa apenas permitido pegar o valor ou algo do tipo eu até entendo, pois é menos trabalhoso do que criar um `método` para pegar esse valor, mas quando é o mais simples eu não entendo. Tem real diferença entre os dois códigos abaixo?

```
public int Numero { get; set; }
public int numero;
```

Comment: Você está livre para abstrair o como vai resgatar ou como vai salvar o valor. Sem falar que podem existir frameworks que vão atrás de métodos `getters` e `setters` (a existência desses frameworks é comum demais em Java, não sei tanto quanto a C#)

Comment: Realmente, estava usando `SQLite.net`para `Xamarin` e para usar algumas funcionalidades como o autoincrement, se não me engano, precisa-se `getter` e `setter`.